# about the verb 'bias'

Tags: vocabulary

I am not sure what difference, if any, exists between the following two phrases:

1. bias the report in Peter's favor.
2. bias Peter in favor of the report.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The report is about Peter. The authors place in the report enough information favorable to Peter and eliminate enough information unfavorable to Peter so as to slant the report in his favor.  I.e., people reading the report will think highly of Peter.
2. Peter has to decide whether the report (which isn't necessarily about him) is good or bad. People decide to tell Peter how good the report is and also decide not to tell him bad things about the report so that Peter will have a favorable opinion of the report.